# a_n coeffisent in fourier. like function

Tags: fourier-series

i want to find the fourier transform of this function:

[image]

and since it is an like function the b_n is zero.

And also since it the function is like i thought i could only take the integral from 0 to pi and multiple it by 2, but then i get the wrong a_0 and a_n coeffisent. howcome?

$$ a_0 = \frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)dx$$
$$ a_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})dx$$

$$ a_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}2\int_{0}^{\pi}sin(x)dx$$
$$ a_n = \frac{2}{2\pi}2\int_{0}^{\pi}sin(x)cos(\frac{n\pi x}{2\pi})dx$$

but how come this be wrong?

Comment: There is a 2 missing in the first $a_0$ and $L = \pi$.

Comment: how come the period be $$\pi$$ and not $$2\pi$$

Comment: The period is $T=2L$